# How to create a auto_increment ID column in PHPmyadmin based on Time column

Tags: mysql

I have a table in phpMyadmin of which I accidentally deleted the primary key "ID" column.
I would like to restore this as it was before but unfortunately I made no backup. I do have a column which holds a timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP type) whenever a record is inserted so I could potentially sort the table based on that. What steps should I take in order to sort the table on the timestamp column and at the same time insert the "ID" column with auto-increment?

I tried various combinations but have been unsuccessful so far. Thanks!

Comment: you can add new column setting with primarykey and auto increament as follows  ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD `columnName`  int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key

Answer (score 2):

As described by you assuming you do not have a backup of the older database I am afraid that is not possible.

Here's why:
Auto-incremented IDs need not be always incremental assuming if few ids are deleted in between

So even if you add the ID column which is again primary and autoincremented I am afraid it may not have its original ids intact, not to mention the worse part suppose they are foreign keys for some other table then we have a plethora of issues over here.

the query below will recreate the ID column for you (Not original ids though, this will be new ids):

```
  ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

Lastly here are a few tips for the future:

1. Avoid using auto-increment id as your primary key. this can be uuids if you want
2. Learning from this incident. always have a backup of databases no matter what. having no backup is like a tightrope walk.

Hope this helps.